# TACL error - HP NONSTOP Tandem

Tags: hp-nonstop

When I run a TACL script on HP NS (from 80')  then I get the following error

```
$volume.subvolume.fooX  File error 11
```

The TACL macro coresponding part is:

```
PURGE $volume.subvolume.fooX
```

I see through the TACL manual, but I could no find list of error codes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The following is from the Guardian User Guide from HP. Chapter 17 page 6. Please don't delete this again. It is very difficult to find help on HP Non-stop.

```
ERROR [ / run-option / ] error-number
```

Answer (score 1):

The **Guardian Procedure Errors and Messages Manual**,Chapter 2 (File-System Errors) describes error 11 as:

*The file is not in the directory or the record is not in the file, or the specified tape file is not on a labeled tape.*

The error program would give the same text if you typed 
    error 11

The manual provides Cause, Effect and Recovery information - probably not needed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

See the manual on file naming.

the value you have listed "subvolume" is the term describing the location of the value.
But the 'value' you can put as a name for a subvolume can only be 8 char long.
Thus your 9 char name 'subvolume' cannot be found (error 11) file not found.

The hierchy;
Drive name (7 char) (it's 8, but the first digit distinguishes it as a drive by the value "$"
ex. $Data01

Subvol (8 char)
Filename (8 char)

Doug

Answer (score 0):

Error 11 means file not found. you can simply write ERROR (error-number) like ERROR 11 on the TACL prompt and it will give you the error description.

Answer (score 0):

If you have variables named Volume and SubVolume and are wanting to use the information stored in those variables, then you need to expand them by putting square brackets around the variable names:

```
Purge $[Volume].[SubVolume].foox
```